# convert a string with locale date time to global time and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following string returned from a service as locale (in my case Tel Aviv, Israel) date time specific to my timezone, for example the original string is: "24/04/15 06:00 AM"

Think about it as a forecast local time.

Now, how do I convert this to any global time, for example: GMT/UTC ?
Then, how to convert this same global time to the exact original string

So far I have this:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm aa"
                dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "ASIA - Israel (UTC + 2)")
                let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("24/04/15 06:00 AM")
```

When I print the date: 2015-04-23 21:00:00 +0000
What is this global time ? I couldn't convert this new date to the original string... don't understand what's this date exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just a note:*

`HH` means 24-hour format. Since you specify AM, you're using 12-hour format, so you should instead use `hh` in the formatter.

Change

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm aa"
```

with

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm aa"
```

Comment: Eric, indeed this helps me on the conversion issue. The code converts correctly on xcode playground, and simulator - but not on my device (iPhone 8.2)

Comment: Let's try something (just a guess): `dateFormatter.locale =  NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` just before `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm aa"`. Does it modify the behaviour on the device?

Comment: you're correct I was wrongly using  the current locale instead of the one matching my need. I ended using: dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "Europe/Athens")